# How do you orientate the helicopter at night?

Tags: helicopter

How do you orientate the helicopter at night?

Comment: Hi @Toni, and welcome to the Aviation StackExchange! In its current form, your question isn't a good fit for this website. Questions should be clear, well-researched, and directly related to aviation -- this question in particular could use some extra research on your part.

Answer (score 3):

Keep the rotor on top!  Keep visible lights below you. Or be instrument trained and use the gyro's which show the orientation of the helicopter to the terrain.